# Swift - UICollectionView: How to auto-layout the label spacing in the Header

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm trying to create a custom calendar, I need to change the spacing of the header labels when the orientation is changed.

I'm using the following code to change the size and spacing between the cells, but how can I do the same for the labels in the header. The header is a custom class.

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    updateCollectionViewLayout(with: size)

}

private func updateCollectionViewLayout(with size: CGSize) {

    let itemSizeForPortraitMode : CGSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    let itemSizeForLandscapeMode: CGSize = CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)
    var minimumItemSpacing: CGFloat

    if let layout = calendarCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
        layout.itemSize = (size.width < size.height) ? itemSizeForPortraitMode : itemSizeForLandscapeMode

        minimumItemSpacing = (size.width -  (7 * 40)) / 6
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = minimumItemSpacing

        layout.invalidateLayout()
        calendarCollectionView.updateConstraints()

    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I added a function to my header custom class:

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {

    super.layoutSubviews()

    var labelFrame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 43, width: self.bounds.size.width / 7.0, height: 20)

    for lbl in self.subviews {

        if lbl.tag == 1 || lbl.tag == 2 || lbl.tag == 3 || lbl.tag == 4 || lbl.tag == 5 || lbl.tag == 6 || lbl.tag == 7 {
            lbl.frame = labelFrame
            labelFrame.origin.x += labelFrame.size.width
        }

    }

}
```